# Determine the number of simple graphs with 10 vertices and 7 edges such that all vertices degree are 0 or 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Determine the number of simple graphs with 10 vertices and 7 edges such that all
vertices degree are 0 or 2.

Confused with that degrees 0 and 2 on simple graphs, any help will do, thank you.

Comment: labelled or unlabeled graphs?

Comment: doesnt say, its a example of final exam on my university

Comment: Start by looking at the definition of a  simple graph and the definition of degree of a vertex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since each vertex has degree 0 or 2, we can see that all the graphs we construct must be the disjoint union of cycle graphs on three or more vertices (two is not allowed, because the graphs must be simple) and singleton graphs.

All graphs satisfying the conditions in the problem can therefore be constructed by partitioning the seven edges into sets of three or more, constructing cycles out of them and topping the vertex count to ten with singleton graphs (isolated vertices). The partition can be done in only two ways:

- one cycle of 7 vertices
- two cycles of 3 and 4 vertices

Hence the answer to the question *if the graph is unlabelled* is two. For the labelled case:

- The graph with $C_7$ has $\binom{10}7×\frac{6!}2=43200$ labellings.
- The graph with $C_3$ and $C_4$ has $\binom{10}3×\binom74×\frac{2!}2×\frac{3!}2=12600$ labellings.
- The number of graphs satisfying the conditions is therefore $43200+12600=55800$.

Comment: This is of course, assuming the graph is unlabelled.  If it were a [labelled graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LabeledGraph.html), then we would need to pick which seven vertices are in the cycle and in what order or we would need to pick which four and three vertices are in the cycles and in what order.  The fact that it specifically mentions that there are ten vertices implies to me that the number of vertices is relevant beyond the point of "are there enough."

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, I've added the labelled case.

Comment: The way the question is stated, it looks unlabeled to me. +1 before the edit.  Better after.